# Is it possible to support add-swap-drop of DB tables in Android ContentProvider?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

I am being asked to provide a dual-cache scheme for syncing cloud DB with device DB.  The requirement is to create a set of tables and then at some point in time, the sync will occur to a mirror of the same set of tables.  When done, the ContentProvider is expected to swap one set for the other without the application noticing.

Is this possible?

Can I add-swap-drop tables safely?
Can I add-swap-drop several tables safely - some activities may be displaying joins?

Comments and ideas are welcome, but it is not an option to "merge sync" the existing tables.

My concern is that there can be outstanding cursors in Activities or Services that are operating on the table-set and no way to assure that they have closed the cursor before the table that it may be accessing is dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible (Even though your two-table requirement from your customer sounds like a really ugly hack.)

Your ContentProvider is expected to serve up a cursor, in response to a specific Content URI.  How that URI gets mapped to a table in the database is completely up to you.

So do this:
Create 2 tables, "data1" and "data2" with an identical database schema.  Fill data1 with your data like normally.  When an app queries your URI, respond with a cursor filled with data out of data1.

Later, fill up data2.  When the command comes and it's time to switch tables, call notifyChange() with the (one) URI you use for that data.  All the cursors that are listening (Your display apps *are* using RegisterContentObserver() aren't they?) will be notified that the data at your URI has changed.  When they get that notify, they'll re-query.  This time, your ContentProvider will answer with data out of table2 instead of table1...  The cursor doesn't know what *table* it's filled from, just what URI.  So to the applications using the data, the change is completely transparent (as long as the two tables have the same schema.)

I've glossed over commanding the switch and saving which table is active.  That's obviously kind of application specific to you, but you should be able to find a good way to persist that information already.

As for table JOINs...  The trick of course is to ensure that the logic to do the JOIN itself happens inside the ContentProvider, not inside the app.  Then, you just switch several sets of tables at once, and do JOIN out of the right sets.

Finally, as for stale Cursors, the Cursor contains a copy of table data, not any reference to the table itself.  So if the table goes away, the Cursor data would be stale, at worst.  It won't hold the table open or the like.  The Cursor keeps a back-reference to the Content URI it came from, not the table.  So, again, when it requeries, it'll work just like above.

Comment: This is consistent with my implementation.  But what about table locking during the swap?  So the table delete would occur after issuing the notifyChange() and assume that all the stale cursors will requery.  Does this satisfy any "paused" Activities that later resume??  I think so.

Comment: Even if there _was_ a paused activity with a stale Cursor, and even if it _did not_ requery, you wouldn't have crashes.  You'd have stale data but no worse.  Once the Cursor is returned from the ContentProvider, there's no long term link back to the CP.  The cursor keeps a copy of all the parameters to the query that generated it (so it can use them to requery) but it keeps no permanent link to the ContentProvider or tables themselves.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  That was my expectation, but I don't have the technical facts to back it up.  I accept your answer.